# PHP nested in jQuery only executes once. I want it to execute every time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having issues with a chunk of PHP/jQuery code.

***Background information:***
My page has 10 divs on it with their own ids, named Q1 - Q10. At page load, all of the divs start off on the page as hidden using the jQuery hide command. 
In PHP, I have an array called "tracker" which has a shuffled list of 10 numbers, ranging from 1-10, with no duplicated numbers. I also have a variable "x" which is used as an index. Both of these variables were declared and populated in some PHP at the top of my page.

***The Problem:***
When the button is pressed for the first time, the code executes perfectly, showing the first random div to the user. All additional clicks do nothing.

***The Outcome I Would Like To See:*** 
every time my button is clicked, a new div is shown to the user.

```
    <script>$('form').click(function()
    {
      <?php
        echo "$('#Q" . $tracker[$x] . "').show();" ;
            $x++;
      ?>

    });
   </script>
```

Thank You in advance for any help provided.

Comment: You must understand the order of operations. PHP runs FIRST and does all the PHP stuff, THEN you end up with HTML/CSS/Javascript which runs SECOND. Thus you can't loop PHP in Javascript.

Comment: @ohmusama I would say more completely that it's the difference in understanding what PHP is and when it gets executed as opposed to what Javascript is and where it get executed. One lives on the server and is processed there, the other is executed on the clients computer without any knowledge of the server from which it was delivered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the random value in javascript on each click -

```
<script>
  $('form').click(function() {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
       $('#Q'+randNum).show();
  });
</script>
```

see this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3cHtc/1/

---

If you want to use your shuffled php array `$tracker`, then you need to add the full array order to your javascript, which can be done using `json_encode()`

```
<script>
  var counter = 0;
  var randNum = <?php echo json_encode($tracker); ?> // print the $tracker array as a json array
  $('form').click(function() {
       $('#Q'+randNum[counter]).show(); 
       counter +=1; // increase the counter
  });
</script>
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3cHtc/4/

Comment: This is not what he wants, he wants to show the divs in linear order

Comment: @ohmusama `showing the first **random** div to the user  .... every time my button is clicked, **a new div** is shown to the user`. OP said **random**, and then **a new** div, not next/linear order

Comment: he has a *shuffled* php array with the random numbers, he needs help opening the next div.

Comment: The second block of code was just what I was looking to do. Thanks for the help.